# how to specify busytimeout value for sqlite database using luasql.sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, lua

I'm trying to find a way to specify a transaction timeout value for my sqlite database.
What I'm trying to accomplished is described in the following link, under the "The timeout method" section:

http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#timeout

I'm using luasql.sqlite3 and I haven't been able to find anything.

I've tried:

```
  env = assert (luasql.sqlite3())  
  con = assert (env:connect(dbname))
  con:busytimeout(2000)
```

and

```
  env = assert (luasql.   
  con = assert (env:connect(dbname))
  con:setbusytimeout(2000)
```

But neither method is recognized. 
If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

I've also tried con:set_busy_timeout(2000) based on the following article:

http://www.nessie.de/mroth/lua-sqlite3/documentation.html#ref20

But it's still a no go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LuaSQL's SQLite library supports bare essential methods as [listed under their manual](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/manual.html). If you want a better library for SQLite, I'd suggest you to try this one: **[LuaSQLite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/index)**

It can easily be installed using [luarocks](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#installation) and the documentation is quite detailed. The [timeout function](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_busy_timeout) is documented too as `busy_timeout()`.